# HEAD detached from refs/heads/newBranch

Tags: git

My Main Branch is master

Current Branch is decimalQuantity

After rebasing master branch to decimalQuantity branch Found conflicts, Resolved conflicts, but it's showing as `HEAD detached from refs/heads/decimalQuantity` and I have few files ready to commit.

What do you mean by this, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve a detached HEAD, reattach it :

```
git checkout decimalQuantity
```

and in the case of modifications forbidding you to checkout with an error message, you can stash them (`git stash`), checkout as mentionned above, then reapply them (`git stash pop`).

Comment: I have tried it, still in same place, HEAD detached from refs/heads/decimalQuantity, Saying "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:" and Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

Comment: Then you should `commit your changes or stash them` before checking out.

Comment: After commit and checkout It's saying =>

On branch decimalQuantity
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/decimalQuantity'.

Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 87ad978 Temp

Next commands to do (9 remaining commands):
   pick bf37697 Temp
   pick aef1a51 Temp
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)

You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'decimalQuantity' on '32cd021'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Yeah, it means the rebase is still going. Finish it as hinted at by git help then you'll be all set. The rebase process was the reason for your detached HEAD in the first place. Not a bug, but an unsettling feature for many ;-)